# How can I use callback functions in groceryCrud for the view record page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I do not know how to set a callback function for the view record page in codeigniter.

I use the callback_column function and it does what I need in the grid view, but on the view record page it does not work.

I searched their site and forum and did not found anything that could help me.

My code looks like:

```
$zeus = new grocery_CRUD();
$zeus->set_theme('bootstrap');
// $zeus->set_language('romanian');

$zeus->set_table('programari');
$zeus->columns(array('id_client', 'id_sala', 'denumire', 'numar_persoane', 'observatii'));

$zeus->callback_column('id_sala',array($this,'_test_function'));

$cod = $zeus->render();

$this->_afiseaza_panou($cod);

public function _test_function($row, $value)
{
  return '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware GroceryCRUD doesn't provide callbacks or another means of overriding the default output in the view state.

The solution to customising this would be to create a custom view to which you will insert the data from your record. This way you can customise the layout and other presentation.

What you would then do is unset the default read view with:

```
$crud->unset_read();
```

And add a new action where there are details on how to do this [here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/add_action).

What to do with the new action is point it to a URL that you map in `routes.php` if necessary and handle it with a new function in your controller. You'll either have to write a model function to retrieve the data since this isn't passed from GC or you can use the action to target a callback and feed `$row` to it via `POST` or something so that the data for the record is accessible in the view. (Look at the example in the link above).

Answer (score 3):

write this lines in \libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php

at line number 3530

```
protected $callback_read_field      = array();
```

than put this function after constructor call

```
public function callback_read_field($field, $callback = null)
{
    $this->callback_read_field[$field] = $callback;

    return $this;
}


//Now update this function to manage the field outputs using callbacks if they are defined for the same
protected function get_read_input_fields($field_values = null)
{
    $read_fields = $this->get_read_fields();

    $this->field_types = null;
    $this->required_fields = null;

    $read_inputs = array();
    foreach ($read_fields as $field) {
        if (!empty($this->change_field_type)
                && isset($this->change_field_type[$field->field_name])
                && $this->change_field_type[$field->field_name]->type == 'hidden') {
            continue;
        }
        $this->field_type($field->field_name, 'readonly');
    }

    $fields = $this->get_read_fields();
    $types  = $this->get_field_types();

    $input_fields = array();

    foreach($fields as $field_num => $field)
    {
        $field_info = $types[$field->field_name];

        if(isset($field_info->db_type) && ($field_info->db_type == 'tinyint' || ($field_info->db_type == 'int' && $field_info->db_max_length == 1))) {
            $field_value = $this->get_true_false_readonly_input($field_info, $field_values->{$field->field_name});
        } else {
            $field_value = !empty($field_values) && isset($field_values->{$field->field_name}) ? $field_values->{$field->field_name} : null;
        }
        if(!isset($this->callback_read_field[$field->field_name]))
        {
            $field_input = $this->get_field_input($field_info, $field_value);
        }
        else
        {
            $primary_key = $this->getStateInfo()->primary_key;
            $field_input = $field_info;
            $field_input->input = call_user_func($this->callback_read_field[$field->field_name], $field_value, $primary_key, $field_info, $field_values);
        }

        switch ($field_info->crud_type) {
            case 'invisible':
                unset($this->read_fields[$field_num]);
                unset($fields[$field_num]);
                continue;
                break;
            case 'hidden':
                $this->read_hidden_fields[] = $field_input;
                unset($this->read_fields[$field_num]);
                unset($fields[$field_num]);
                continue;
                break;
        }

        $input_fields[$field->field_name] = $field_input;
    }

    return $input_fields;
}
```

than call same as other callback functions